# Query with subquery not returning a value that should be returned

Tags: mysql, sql, correlated-subquery

Why this query

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl X
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl Y WHERE X.end_date=Y.start_date)
ORDER BY accommodation_id, start_date
```

does not return the following row?

[image]

I verified the row is not returned adding `AND accommodation_id = 7049` to the `WHERE` clause, so the resulting query is:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_byt_accommodation_vacancies X WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM wp_byt_accommodation_vacancies Y WHERE X.end_date=Y.start_date) AND accommodation_id = 7049 ORDER BY accommodation_id, start_date
```

I verified there aren't rows with `start_date = '2017-04-08` for that `accommodation_id` using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_byt_accommodation_vacancies WHERE accommodation_id = 7049 AND start_date = '2017-04-07'
```

Comment: Please edit your question and clearly show both the current and expected output, as _text_, not as images.

Comment: please post data sample from both the tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use following query

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl X
WHERE NOT EXISTS (  SELECT * 
                    FROM tbl Y 
                    WHERE X.end_date=Y.start_date
                    AND X.accommodation_id = Y.accommodation_id)
ORDER BY accommodation_id, start_date
```

You have forgot to link the key `X.accommodation_id = Y.accommodation_id`